# Form Submit request getting aborted with 204 status code

Tags: form-submit

I am facing issue with form submit request sometimes and it getting aborted with 204 status code.

Please find the below code.

```
var f = document.forms[0];
try {
    f.Guid.Value = "xx";
    f.action = "Handler1.ashx";
    f.submit();
} catch (e) {
    SetError(e, null, "General");
}
return false;
```

Comment: What is the programming language? Also 204 (HTTP) is no abort, response has just no content: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: It’s happening in JavaScript and all the browsers.After clearing the cache it is working fine.